# Height Map Visual Issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes

I have a height map which was painted in Substance Painter, but when I use it in Blender I get some crazy visuals. This is in Cycles.
[image: visual glitch caused by height map]
Here's what the Shader Nodes look like. Each image is labeled. And I'm using Non-Color Data when applicable (Normal, Height, Roughness).
[image: node setup]
And here's the arms height map.
[image: arms height map]
Here's what it looks like at scale 0.1. The extruded areas are supposed to follow the normal of the lights and such. But the height map clearly looks like its randomly extruded vertices and is very sharp.
[image: scale 0.1]

Comment: DIsplacement textures operate in the 0-1 range with white being 1 and 0 being black. The default unit scale for displacement in blender is 1m (with a scale of 1). Blender also places the default midlevel at 0.5, therefore black areas in the displacement texture will displace vertices -0.5m (down), and vice versa, white areas will displace vertices 0.5m (up), with the default scale of 1. Therefore, to get better results, try changing the scale to 0.2 or less.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett even with Scale of 0.2, it looks absolutely rancid. If I put it all the way down to 0.01 it's minimal, but also apparent that the geometry being extruded is somehow not lining up with where it should be extruding. I added an edit of the post to show this new image.

Comment: Yeah, not sure then. It night have to do with your UV seams, but it's hard to tell without seeing them. I also see you're using UDIM tiles - might an incorrect UV map have something to do with it?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I only have one UV Map, and when looking at the UV on the image and it should be working based on that